# Change UV wrap size for Image Layer BUT keep UV wrap size for Height Map Layer

Tags: uv, image, texture-painting, height-map

This is a question about UV unwrapping.  Simple version.  I want to unwrap the base color image and the image I use as a "height map" (for shading) on the same surface as two different sizes.

[image]

What I did:

- I made this cube (a wall) and I added a texture to use as a height map.  The first image shows how I set it up--using a "bump node"
  -The second image show that I stretch the UV map larger than the picture to make the detail smaller on the cube (wall)
- I want to draw on this cube (draw graffiti on what is supposed to be a wall.)
  So I add another image and use it as the "Base Color" -- the third image you can see that how I simply just added it as a base color.  Nothing fancy.
- But now when I draw on the wall, it repeats because the UV unwrap is stretched because I stretched it for the first image (the image I used as a height map).

So I think "Easy fix" and...

[image]

So I shrink the UV wrap.  So the UV wrap will stretch to the complete wall.
As can be seen in Image 5 and Image 6

But, as can be seen in the last image, the detail of the height map also stretches.
This is because the Height Map UV wrap automatically changes to match the UV wrap of the image.

Is there a way I can stretch the image (that is the base color) to the whole wall BUT keep the image (that is the height map) small?

I hope the images made my question understandable.
I really appreciate the help here!

(Quick answer to a question that might come up:
-The image used for the height map is already very very large so I don't want to add a bigger one.  Also I like the repeating texture.  Moreover, I have many walls (many surfaces) in my project.  This is the only wall I want to draw on.)

Thank you!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use several UV maps. Here I've created a second UV map node and plugged a *(Input) UV Map* node (with this second UV map selected) into the second *Image Texture* (the circle). By default the first *Image Texture* (oranges crosses) will still use the first UV map:

[image]

You could even keep only one UV map but change the *Scale* parameters of the *Mapping* node that is plugged into the second *Image Texture* to make the circle bigger (here I'm using an *(Input) Value* node to change the parameters more easily):

[image]